# How to set cookie using php through $.post request

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, browser, .post

i'm trying to set cookie in a $.post request.

My problem is that i want to delete cookie on browser close so i try this:

```
$.post("cookie.php",{name:name,surname:surname,usn:usn,psw:psw},function(msg){
   ...
});
```

cookie.php:

```
setcookie("code",$name,"/");
```

//  i don't add expiration time because i read on the web that in this way cookies will be deleted on browser close.

If i don't add `/` parameter ( i read ) my cookie are not applied to every path..

but in this way i retrieve this:

```
Warning:  setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in ....
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

```
setcookie("code",$name, 0, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that you are trying to pass parameter 4 without having passed parameter 3, so the compiler can't understand what you mean.

Set parameter 3 like so:

```
setcookie("code",$name, 0, "/");
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use jquery cookie plugin

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Using.

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```